# Adding Previous Tenant's Name to PSEG Bill for School Enrollment

Tags: fraud, new-jersey, school, utility-bills

The previous tenant wants me to add her name to my PSEG bill so her daughter can stay in the neighborhood school. It seemed a bit odd to me, any legal red flags I should be aware of?

Comment: Is she going to pay the bill?  And what is PSEG?

Comment: She mentioned covering the bill, although I neither requested nor require it. PSEG is New Jersey's utility providing gas and electric services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being asked to conspire to mislead a government official and to help facilitate fraud. This is a crime, and is a felony in some jurisdictions.

While crimes of this type are rarely discovered or prosecuted, there are [examples of people being prosecuted for similar conduct and sentenced to significant prison terms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanya_McDowell).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was very helpful, I’m glad I asked.